# mySQL Rotate Table 90 degrees

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with ~100 columns, and only one row. Each column is a date, and each entry in a column is a corresponding value. I want to query the table so that it is displayed with only 2 columns: Date, Value.

```
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  Date1 |  Date2 |  Date3 |  Date4 |  Date5 |  Date6 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | Value4 | Value5 | Value6 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
```

What I want:

```
|--------|--------|
|  Dates | Values |
|--------|--------|
|  Date1 | Value1 |
|--------|--------|
|  Date2 | Value2 |
|--------|--------|
|  Date3 | Value3 |
|--------|--------|
|  Date4 | Value4 |
|--------|--------|
|  Date5 | Value5 |
|--------|--------|
|  Date6 | Value6 |
```

Comment: ~100 columns with 1 row smells pretty bad. That poor design will give you more and more trouble every time you'll try to do things. Fix your design first

Comment: didn't design it, but thats what im planning on doing, after i query the data

Comment: Well, do it first. When your bike has a punctured tire, will you first inflate it and then fix it or the opposite?

Comment: @Cid If i wanted bicycle advice i would be on tumblr

Comment: Gather columns list via INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. Build multi-UNION query text. Execute.

Comment: Was it actually for MySQL or bigquery?

Comment: Btw, what a terrible answer in that post that is marked as "This question already has an answer here"!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use this column's design .. but anyway if you need  the result for the columns in separated  rows  you could try using UNION ALL

```
select 'date1', date1 
from mytable 
union all 
select 'date2', date2 
from mytable 
......
union all 
select 'date100', date100
from mytable
```

And as suggested in comment by @akina you could build the query dynamically using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`